# IIS URL Rewrite: @import in <style> section?

Tags: iis-7, teamcity, rewrite

I'm attempting to put JetBrains TeamCity (which uses TomCat on port 81) behind IIS 7, so that http://www.example.com/teamcity/ is proxied to http://myserver:81/. I think I've got it mostly working, except that TeamCity outputs @import in the `<style>` element. I can't figure out how to define an outbound rule to deal with this.

How do I get URL rewrite to deal with this?

Or, alternatively, can I teach TeamCity about the alternative virtual directory, so that it prefixes everything with `/teamcity`?

Or, more alternatively, is there a better way to put TeamCity behind IIS 7.5?

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** The following doesn't completely work: some of the Javascript is problematic, and the logout redirect is broken.

Options:

1. Host TeamCity in a Tomcat installation that's listening to `/teamcity`; then there'll be no need for outbound rules. I've got this working for a drupal installation.
2. Redirect `teamcity.example.com` instead (no virtual directory). There are [example steps for this](http://blog.endjin.com/2010/11/a-step-by-step-guide-to-hosting-teamcity-in-iis-7/) elsewhere. This will require some DNS CNAMEs and a wildcard certificate (if using HTTPS for external access).

*I'll leave the other instructions here for posterity...*

You can configure URL Rewrite to rewrite any part of the text, by setting `filterByTags="None"`.

So I now have the following in `C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\web.config`:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <!-- Anything to http://www.example.com/teamcity/ should be
             rewritten to http://teamcity:81/ -->
        <rule name="TeamCity (/teamcity)">
          <match url="^teamcity/(.*)" />
          <serverVariables>
            <!-- URL Rewrite can't deal with Encoding: gzip; turn that off. -->
            <set name="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="" />
          </serverVariables>
          <action type="Rewrite"
                  url="http://teamcity:81/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
```

That's the inbound rule; there are three outbound rules:

```
      <outboundRules>
```

Login redirects:

```
        <!-- 302 Redirects (for the login page, e.g.) need to be rewritten. -->
        <rule name="Teamcity (/teamcity) - Redirect" preCondition="IsRedirect">
          <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_LOCATION"
                 pattern="http://[^/]+/(.*)" />
          <action type="Rewrite"
                  value="http://www.example.com/teamcity/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
```

Normal HTML rewriting:

```
        <!-- Links in HTML need to be rewritten. -->
        <rule name="TeamCity (/teamcity) - HTML" preCondition="IsHTML">
          <!-- I've ellided the other tag types here; you might want them. -->
          <match filterByTags="A, ..."
                 pattern="^(.*)" />
          <action type="Rewrite"
                  value="http://www.example.com/teamcity/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
```

@import of CSS files:

```
        <!-- TeamCity uses @import for styles; fix that. -->
        <rule name="TeamCity (/teamcity) - Style" preCondition="IsHTML">
          <match filterByTags="None" pattern="@import &quot;/" />
          <action type="Rewrite" value="@import &quot;/teamcity/" />
        </rule>
```

And some pre-conditions:

```
        <preConditions>
          <preCondition name="IsRedirect">
            <add input="{RESPONSE_STATUS}" pattern="302" />
          </preCondition>
          <preCondition name="IsHTML">
            <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
          </preCondition>
        </preConditions>
      </outboundRules>

    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

It appears to work, but I'll come back and update this answer if I find anything else.